# Lambda Layer issue: Python module not found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

**Overall Usecase**: I have lambda function and I am adding custom python package layers to the lambda using terraform. Lambda was created successfully and also layer was attached to lambda.

Here is my folder structure I have installed the python google API library in `gogoleapis` folder using the below command

**Edit-1 Updates**
`pip install google-cloud-iam -t /Users/Documents/GitHub/Project/project/step_function/common/googleapis`

```
project-dir
     |-step_function
                   |-common
                           |-googleapis
                           |-zip
                   |-python
                           |-lambda_function.py
                   |-zip
                        |-lambda_function.zip
                   |-main.tf
     |-main.tf
```

I have added block to create zip folder of the googleapis and creating layers. Googleapis filder contains all google cloud libraries needed for python function.

```
# Add Google API Layers
data "archive_file" "googleapis_layer_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir = "${path.module}/common/googleapis"
  output_path = "${path.module}/common/zip/googleapis.zip"
}

# Python googleapis layer
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "googleapis_layer" {
    filename            = "${path.module}/common/zip/googleapis.zip"
    layer_name          = "googleapis"
    source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.snow_gcp_permission_handler_archive.output_base64sha256
    compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
}
```

Lambda function gcp_get_assignment_role_data.py code which import package from layers. I have simply import the google packages which are part of googleapis folder.

**Lambda function: gcp_get_assignment_role_data.py**

```
import json,os
from datetime import date
import boto3, requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return "hello-world"
```

When I try to run the lambda, function returing below error. I tried to look at the AWS documenation but all steps leads to manual creation and adding lambda layers to the function. But I want to create/add to the lambda using Terraform.

**Edit-1 -- Reproduce actual error**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'gcp_get_assignment_role_data': No module named 'google'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided indicates a syntax error in the Python code module named `gcp_get_assignment_role_data`. The error specifically points to an unexpected indent on `line 4` of the `gcp_get_assignment_role_data.py` file. Python is sensitive to indentation, so this error occurs when the indentation level is not as expected.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the indentation in the `gcp_get_assignment_role_data.py` file is consistent and correct.

Comment: this is line number 4 in the python code `import google.oauth2.credentials`. I am trying to import the libraries from the layer added to lambda.

Comment: Check the indentation in your python code, I think that is your issue with the code

Comment: I have updated the original post, now syntax error looks good but the actual error is still hitting about missing the module.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue was with my directory structure when creating and uploading files to layers.
Layers libraries won't work if the directory name is anything other than Python. I have updated my directory structure and finally API worked as expected.

```html
project-dir
     |-step_function
                   |-common
                           |-python
                           |-python.zip
                   |-python
                           |-lambda_function.py
                   |-zip
                        |-lambda_function.zip
                   |-main.tf
     |-main.tf
```